# Многие ко многим sql

Tags: mysql, sql

В чем ошибка запроса?

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM departments 
    INNER JOIN users ON departments.id = (
        SELECT d_id FROM d_to_u 
            INNER JOIN users ON users.id = d_to_u.u_id
    )"
);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch()

Comment: Открой программу по работе с БД, вбей туда запрос и посмотри какой результат выдает.

Comment: Что такое "melf запрос"?

Comment: ...туда запрос*

Comment: #1052 - Column 'd_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: у тебя колонка `d_id` определена в двух таблицах, поэтому SELECT не может понять откуда именно вынимать. надо указать принадлежность таблице

Comment: Исправил: $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM departments INNER JOIN users ON departments.id = (SELECT d_to_u.d_id FROM d_to_u INNER JOIN users ON users.id = d_to_u.u_id)");
Теперь выдает: #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Commands_out_of_sync.html

Comment: @VasyaPupkin Это уже другой вопрос :) Вы не выбрали предыдущий результат до конца

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, так:

```
SELECT * FROM d_to_u JOIN departments ON d_to_u.d_id = departments.id 
            INNER JOIN users ON users.id = d_to_u.u_id
```